# IOS GPS Caching , GPS without Internet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am trying to implement the GPS based application in ios, that should work in offline mode, means if internet connection is not available, our GPS should work to show the route or map.

I have used Map But, but not able to get it.

How can I to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are going to have to ask a much more specific question, with code examples of anything you have tried, showing where you get stuck, if you want to get real answers here.

Comment: I asked about the idea to implement it , else MapBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location services do not require an internet connection. Whenever it's available the accuracy is increased but they work offline as well.

Comment: so i dont need to do anything in my code to make it work in offline mode.??

Comment: I think Sachin is after a solution that includes GPS _and_ offline maps.

Comment: @SachinSiwal, you can get your GPS location without internet (GPS is a satellite service) - but you need to get your map data from somewhere, so that you can show your location on a map. What's wrong with MapBox?

Comment: @HeWas then he should clarify better his question. :)

Comment: Thanks guys , i was not aware of Apples vector map, and GPS concept , now i got what i wanted to do .

Comment: @SachinSiwal, i also face the same issue. can you post your code for that?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, i also face the same issue. Can you post your answer with code?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add - If you're testing on an Apple device which does NOT have cellular (i.e. GSM data connection) then it probably won't have a dedicated GPS chipset.

I found with iOS iPad 7th Gen when wifi is turned off, the location updates (i.e. location services) will also stop updating.

Apple Reference :
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250902909